# table extraction from docx

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to extract tables in a given document (in docx format) to further process the information in unix environment. The intermediate goal is to have the data in a tabular format (csv or xml) for each of the tables in the separate files. Hence, I was attempting to generate the xml format using xslt but have failed. I am new to xslt and would like some guidance. I would not like to use perl/other languages as tables are not standardized.

I would like to understand,

1. How can one identify and differentiate between various tables?
2. How do I create new files in based on identifiers of tables in xslt?

---

Below is the xml file generated by unzip'ing docx file. 
This contains two tables.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14"><w:body><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>Node Selection and Pattern Matching</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>In XSLT stylesheets, template rules for node selection and pattern matching are applied via the select attribute of the xsl:apply-templates command and the match attribute of the xsl:template element, respectively. A specification can be created to determine how to resolve issues in the event that a multiple number of applicable template rules exist, or alternately, when there are no applicable template rules at all.</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0"/><w:tbl><w:tblPr><w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/><w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/><w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/></w:tblPr><w:tblGrid><w:gridCol w:w="3116"/><w:gridCol w:w="3117"/><w:gridCol w:w="3117"/></w:tblGrid><w:tr w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidTr="003404B0"><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="3116" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0"><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">Table1 </w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="3117" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>heading</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="3117" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>Text</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidTr="003404B0"><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="3116" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>body</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="3117" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>Blah</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="3117" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>blah</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidTr="003404B0"><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="3116" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>Body2</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="3117" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>Blah2</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="3117" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>Blah2</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr></w:tbl><w:p w:rsidR="006C4C5A" w:rsidRDefault="006C4C5A"/><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>Node Selection</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>With the select attribute of xsl:apply-templates command, an XPath description can be used to either (1) select a multiple number of nodes with identical names, or (2) select a multiple number of nodes with differing names. Under scenario (1), using XPath to designate "ProductList/ Product" results in the selection of two Product element nodes.</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:tbl><w:tblPr><w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/><w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/><w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/></w:tblPr><w:tblGrid><w:gridCol w:w="2383"/><w:gridCol w:w="2420"/><w:gridCol w:w="2194"/><w:gridCol w:w="2353"/></w:tblGrid><w:tr w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidTr="003404B0"><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2383" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="0042011C"><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">Table1 </w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2420" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="0042011C"><w:r><w:t>heading</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2194" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="0042011C"><w:r><w:t>Col1</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2353" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="0042011C"><w:r><w:t>Text</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidTr="003404B0"><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2383" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="0042011C"><w:r><w:t>body</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2420" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="0042011C"><w:r><w:t>Blah</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2194" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="0042011C"><w:r><w:t>Col1 Blah</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2353" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="0042011C"><w:r><w:t>blah</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidTr="003404B0"><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2383" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="0042011C"><w:r><w:t>Body2</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2420" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="0042011C"><w:r><w:t>Blah2</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2194" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="0042011C"><w:r><w:t>Col1 Blah2</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2353" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="0042011C"><w:r><w:t>Blah2</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidTr="003404B0"><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2383" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>B</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>ody3</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2420" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>Blah3</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2194" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>Col1 Blah3</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2353" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="003404B0"><w:r><w:t>Blah3</w:t></w:r><w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/></w:p></w:tc></w:tr></w:tbl><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="003404B0"/><w:p w:rsidR="003404B0" w:rsidRDefault="003404B0" w:rsidP="003404B0"/><w:sectPr w:rsidR="003404B0"><w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/><w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/><w:cols w:space="720"/><w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>
```

---

My experiment: The output is just the dump of all the text, even consuming the spaces.

xsl file:

```
<xsl:transform
        version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
        extension-elements-prefixes="dyn">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/tbl">
  </xsl:template>
    </xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Your template `match="/tbl"` won't match anything because `tbl` is not at the root level of the document. Hence, only the default action occurs which copies the text content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question is now, nobody will be able to answer it because a) you are asking many different things at the same time while b) not being very specific about your requirements. But I will try to walk you through the difficulties.

You mention at least those problems in your question:

- Find and extract certain elements from an OpenXML document
- Retain the identity of those elements
- Creating several outputfiles as XML or CSV

**Finding `tbl` elements**

First of all, you have to be aware that all the elements (and most attributes) in OpenXML (the format behind *.docx) are *prefixed*, that is, they are in a *namespace*. This has a lot of practical consequences, but the only important thing for now is: as far as your XSLT processor is concerned, a `tbl`element is entirely different from one that is called `w:tbl`. So, if your template matches `tbl` elements, it will never find those you are actually looking for.

Any namespace that is present in your input XML and that is relevant in your XSLT stylesheet must be redeclared there:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
```

Then, write a template that matches `w:tbl`elements:

```
<xsl:template match="//w:tbl">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

In other words, find `tbl` elements that are in the WordML "main" namespace. If this is the only template in your stylesheet, there will be two `tbl`elements in the result.

**Uniquely identify elements**

In XSLT, the correct way to endow elements with a unique identity is by adding an `ID` attribute. This is done by a function called `generate-id()`. The following template is just one of many ways to incorporate this function into your code.

```
<xsl:template match="//w:tbl">
    <tbl id="{generate-id()}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Creating several output files**

If you are using XSLT 1.0, there is no standard way to create several outputs from the same stylesheet. You would have to use an extension function. On the other hand, if your XSLT processor supports XSLT 2.0, you can use the `xsl:result-document` element to create several output documents, CSV or XML.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, your input has certainly helped. Could you please let me know in case you have any beginner's guide to xslt.

Comment: @user1495523 You are welcome. There are many tutorials for XSLT - you'll easily find one on Google.